# Is there a similar notion to the domain dual to codomain and range

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, function-and-relation-composition

Given a function $f\colon X \to Y$, $X$ is called the "domain", $Y$ is called the "codomain" and the range of $f$ is defined to be the set, $\{ y \in Y \mid \exists x \in X \colon y=f(x) \}$

We can extend this concept to binary relations. We call a set "graph(of a binary relation)" $R$ a set whose only elements are ordered pairs, i.e. there exist sets $A$ and $B$ such that $R \subseteq A \times B$. Notice that the sets $A$ and $B$ are not unique, since $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset \times \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subseteq \{ \emptyset \} \times \{ \emptyset \}$.

For this reason if $R \subseteq A \times B$, we define a binary relation as the triplet $(A, B, R)$. Now, if we were to analogously define the "codomain" and the "range", the codomain is defined as $B$ and the range is defined as $\{ y \mid (\exists x)((x, y) \in R) \}$. But how would we define the domain? We could define is as $A$, but also as the set $\{ x \mid (\exists y)((x, y) \in R) \}$. With functions the two sets are equal since functions are total relations. I was wondering if there is a standard notion for these two sets, since they would pop up in algebra with sets.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be standard to say that, for a relation $(A,B,R)$,

- $A$ is the domain,
- $B$ is the codomain,
- $\{y \mid \exists x ((x,y) \in R)\}$ is the range, and
- $\{x \mid \exists y ((x,y) \in R)\}$ is the **corange**.

As you note, the range and corange are determined entirely by the set $R$, while the domain and codomain cannot be determined uniquely by $R$ and instead must be specified as part of the data of the relation.

Comment: Yes, but what I was wondering is if there is some well known accepted notation/name for the corange. Personally, I haven't heared in my college classes, but I might now have enough mathematical culture. Using notions such as corange is useful when we talk about total relations, a relation is total iff its corange equals its domain.

Comment: I think the term "corange" is unusual, so it should be introduced and defined whenever you use it. On the other hand, as far as I know, there is no other accepted name for this notion.

Comment: yes, corange seems unusual to me as well, and moreover, we could argue it is more intuitive to write the terms beginning with "co" to the concepts that are on the "right side" when we are talking about arrows, like "domain" is on "the left" and "codomain" is on "the right".